# How can I start building universal conda packages?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, pypi, python-wheel

Now I am maintaining several pure Python packages which I am publishing as both source and wheels onto PYPI repository but I want to start publishing them on conda too.

I was surprised not to find any clean information on how to do this. How can I do it?

Note, I don't want to have to build tons of platform specific conda packages for all combinations of Python version and operating system platforms, especially because these packages are pure-python.

Comment: https://conda-forge.github.io/

Comment: you may want to check out how other  people are doing it. See e.g. the community project https://github.com/conda-forge. The idea others are following is to build a infrastructure that automatically builds packages for different OS, whenever an update is pushed.